# hvplot line plot y axis values all over the place and not in increasing order

Tags: python-3.x, dashboard, hvplot

I am trying to create an interactive dashboard with panel in jupiter notebook which i have been able to with just one kink. The y axis is not in increasing order. More or less the graph is plotting a (x,y) coordinate instead of a line plot. Please see image below. Can anyone help get this formatted so it looks like a line plot?

code below:

```
df2f_pipeline =( df2f[ (df2f.Segment==select)].groupby(['Ticker','Date'])
yaxis_measure].sum().astype(float).map(lambda n: '{:.2%}'.format(n))
.to_frame()
.reset_index()
.sort_values(by=['Ticker','Date'])
.reset_index(drop=True)
)

df2f_pipeline 

my_plot = df2f_pipeline.hvplot(x ='Date', y='rate',title=' Rate change By Ticker')

my_plot.opts(xrotation=90)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh2SB.png)

Comment: There is really not much data in your table in the picture. You can also format and provide it as a text table.

Comment: Try converting the `Date` column to datetime, it might be that it's a string object, in which case hvPlot will interpret it as categorical data.